# How to correctly mock a function in a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a function that lives in my reducer file that does this:

```
const myResult = (a, b) => {
    return a*b
}
```

then later in my reducer

```
return {
        ...state,
        result: myResult(valA, valB)
}
```

how do I mock out state.a and state.b so that I can correctly pass them in to the function in the test file?

currently it's just saying that valA and valB are undefined

Comment: I think I need to see more code before I can understand what you're asking. Where are valA and valB supposed to come from? What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: @MikeBell they get passed into the reducer as arguments. im trying to test that when a specific action gets fired, then the result is expected

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution if `myResult` isn't being tested directly is to just mock it out completely.

Comment: using jest mock method stubs?